# is the extensive health check for connection essential in okhttp3?

Tags: okhttp

In okhttp, it makes a 1 ms connection health check for every request. It has obvious influence in my application.

What's this check for?
Is it possible to add a config to disable the check?

```
    if (doExtensiveChecks) {
      try {
        int readTimeout = socket.getSoTimeout();
        try {
          socket.setSoTimeout(1);
          if (source.exhausted()) {
            return false; // Stream is exhausted; socket is closed.
          }
          return true;
        } finally {
          socket.setSoTimeout(readTimeout);
        }
      } catch (SocketTimeoutException ignored) {
        // Read timed out; socket is good.
      } catch (IOException e) {
        return false; // Couldn't read; socket is closed.
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious fix would be to ensure you are using HTTP/2, which would skip this work on the socket and rely on pings etc.

FWIW extensive checks are based on the HTTP method, so should not be an issue with GET operations.

```
    // We need the network to satisfy this request. Possibly for validating a conditional GET.
    val doExtensiveHealthChecks = request.method != "GET"
    val exchange = transmitter.newExchange(chain, doExtensiveHealthChecks)
```

Is this an option?